# Окно поверх остальных в Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Пытаюсь сделать окно, которое бы отображало некоторую информацию при переключении из моего приложения на запущенный им браузер. В результате на данный момент испробовано:

- Стиль формы: fsStayOnTop;
- Перегрузка CreateParams с добавлением стиля
  WS_EX_TOPMOST;
- Вызов SetWindowPos с параметром HWND_TOPMOST в OnShow() и по таймеру;

В любом случае Хром, который вызывается через команду ShellExecute(), перекрывает это окно... да и остальные приложения тоже. TopMost работает только по отношению к другим формам моего приложения.

Возможно кто-нибуlь уже сталкивался с таким поведением и знает как обойти проблему?

P.S: Окно без рамки (BorderStyle = []), Delphi XE2, Windows 10 build 14393;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем выяснилось, что Delphi зачем-то снимает со всех своих форм флаг "поверх всех окон" при деактивации приложения и снова устанавливает при активации.

В связи с этим изложенная выше проблема была решена через обработчик событий Application.OnDeactivate:

```
procedure TfmMainForm.appEventsDeactivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.RestoreTopMosts;
end;
```